# For all sets $A$ and $B$, if $A^c ⊆ B$ then $A ∪ B = U$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

> For all sets $A$ and $B$, if $\;A^c ⊆ B$ then $A ∪ B = U$

I am having difficulty starting to disprove an alleged set property through the use of a counterexample or if it is true then try to prove it.

We have been told to assume all sets are subets of a universal set U.

Comment: Maybe try drawing a picture?

Comment: You could also just dualize your previous question ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note**: $A \cup A^C= U$.

Since $A^C\subseteq B$, what can you conclude about $A\cup B?$?

---

For all $x$, $x \in U \iff x \in A$ or $x \in A^C$.

If $x \in A$, then clearly $x \in A\cup B$.
If $x \notin A$, then $x \in A^C$, so since $A^C \subseteq B$, $x \in B$, so $x \in A\cup B$.

If $x \in A\cup B$, then $x\in A \cup(A^C \cup (B\setminus A^C))$. But $B \setminus A^C \subseteq A$.
So $x \in A \lor x \in A^C \lor x\in B \setminus A^C$ 
 $ \implies x \in A \lor x \in A^C \lor x \in A \implies x \in A \lor x \in A^C \implies x \in U$

Comment: The idea is, every element which isn't in $A$ is in $B$. 
So $A$ together with all elements which are not in $A$ will be $U$.

Comment: @amWhy: very nice answer! +1

Answer (score 4):

If $x\in U$, then $x\in A$ or $x\in A^C$. If $x\in A$ then $x\in A\cup B$ and if $x\in A^C$ since $A^C\subset B$ then we have $x\in A\cup B$.

Comment: Yes! one direction Amy.

Comment: @amWhy The universality of $U$ should take care of the other direction.

Answer (score 1):

You know $A^c\subseteq B$. Take the complement of both sides to see that $B^c \subseteq A$. So, $B \cup B^c \subseteq B \cup A$. But, the set on the left of the containment is equal to ... . Now, draw your conclusion.